# Why are the item effects supressed?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I have equipped my rogue with a bunch of a nice items offering an attribute bonus. Yet when I check the character sheet, I get the information that some of them are suppressed yet it is not explained why.

It be great to know how the item bonus stack or are suppressed.

In my case it looks like this:

[image: Character sheet of supressed stats]

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can stack effects via items; 3 items with + might will only confer the best bonus of the three. Your only way to gain better bonuses is to find an item that has more of that particular stat.

Supposedly (according to the manual) rings stack, but I don't feel like that's been my experience. (edit: rings should stack with other effects, but not with each other)

Comment: I haven't found rings of Deflection stack with a cloak giving Deflection. So I expect they follow the same rules of stacking, only the best bonus.